# How do I make a RadioSelect have a image as radio value?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Review

    widgets = {
        'tipo' : forms.RadioSelect(),
    }
```

But I want to use images as the values of my radio buttons, the image will vary according to the option, like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="id_tipo_0" value="UP" name="tipo" /><img src="/images/thumb_up.gif"/>
<input type="radio" id="id_tipo_1" value="DOWN" name="tipo" /><img src="/images/thumb_DOWN.gif"/>
```

I have no clues on how to achieve this.

Comment: You can't, with regular css. It's an OS-level control. You can fake it with javascript, but there's nothing to control the actual on-screen drawing of a radio element.

Comment: If I hardcode the form, mimicking django's form.as_p output (names and id's), would it work?

Answer (score 12):

There is a nice solution for this issue!

A [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/) has the method `label_from_instance(self, obj)`. This method is called for every option in the ModelChoiceField.

You can overwrite `ModelChoiceField.label_from_instance` with:

```
def label_from_instance(obj):
    """
    Shows an image with the label
    """
    image = conditional_escape(obj.thumbnail_image.url)
    title = conditional_escape(obj.title)

    label = """<img src="%s" />%s""" % (image, title)

    return mark_safe(label)
```

**Note:** you need to use `mark_safe`, otherwise the renderer will escape the `img` tag. Do apply the `conditional_escape` to the user input values (title and url).

If you want to use a regular `ChoiceField` you can just add HTML to the `choices` parameter and add `mark_safe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override RadioSelect (and RadioFieldRenderer) class.

OR! you can use jquery ( or something similar) to insert your img dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_tipo_0").after('<img src="/images/thumb_up.gif"/>')
  $("#id_tipo_1").after('<img src="/images/thumb_down.gif"/>')
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain more? It's the first time I try customizing a form.
If I just write {{form.tipo}} it prints all the options, I want to render different images for each option, base on the option value.

Comment: {{ form.tipo }} will also render the two radio buttons as is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Django form rendering function, you'll have to use javascript to modifiy the DOM, and this will be a mess because the names of the option are rendered just after the input tag, not enclosed in any tag...

If your form does not have any other tags, go ahead, just write your input just as in your example, carefully using the Django  names and values for the radio input, add a submit button, a CSRF token and that's all, you'll be able to validate your form in the view like if it was rendered via {{form.as_p}}

Comment: I think I will drop django's form rendering. What problems I may have in the future?
I don't really like defining HTML and CSS attrs in python classes..

Comment: The only problem is that's not DRY, if you change your field name "tipo", you'll have to edit your template to reflect the change. Not a big problem, if you d'ont start do this on every form.

Comment: I read about extending RadioFieldRenderer and overriding the method render, but I still can't find a way to change the value. In this class, the tag is already created and it's only possible to change surrounding code, like this:
return mark_safe(u'\n%s\n' % u'\n'.join([u'%s' % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))